# Additional validation to wpf form

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a xaml form control for a helpdesk system which checks to see if fields are completed. If they are then the user is allowed to save the form. There is also an override so when in template mode a user can make changes without the required validation. The code is below

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

//Additional
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;

//SCSM
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Configuration;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.DataModel;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ConsoleFramework;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.WpfControls;
using Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.GenericForm;

//Local
using ChangeFormControl.Validation;

namespace ChangeFormControl
{
    public partial class ValidationControl : UserControl
    {
        public ValidationControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.DataContext != null && this.DataContext is IDataItem)
            {
                //Do not add validation if in template mode
                if (!FormUtilities.Instance.IsFormInTemplateMode(this)) ProcessControls();
            }
        }

        private void ProcessControls()
        {
            try
            {
                //Attempt to get the parent TabControl of our custom control
                //There is a TabControl near the top of the tree, we want the one below that
                DependencyObject doParentRoot = GetParentDependancyObject(this, "System.Windows.Controls.TabControl");

                //Did we get the TabControl?
                if (doParentRoot != null)
                {
                    //Now process each TabItem on the tab control
                    foreach (DependencyObject doChild in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(doParentRoot))
                    {
                        //Is this a TabItem?
                        if (doChild.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Controls.TabItem")
                        {
                            //Process each child on current tab to find ones we want and add validation rules
                            AddValidation(doChild);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        //Navigates the Logical tree for passed parent and adds required validation
        private void AddValidation(DependencyObject rootparent)
        {
            //Navigate the logical tree for the children          
            foreach (var rootChild in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(rootparent))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (rootChild is DependencyObject)
                    {

                        if (rootChild is TextBox && ((TextBox)rootChild).Name == "titleTextBox")
                        {
                            //Add the rule so that this property is now required
                            TextBox tb = (TextBox)rootChild;
                            TextRule rule = new TextRule();
                            BindingOperations.GetBinding(tb, TextBox.TextProperty).ValidationRules.Add(rule);
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }

                //Process further logical children of this child
                if (rootChild is DependencyObject) AddValidation(rootChild as DependencyObject);
            }
        }

        //Returns specified parent object, if found, if name is empty, then navigate to top
        private DependencyObject GetParentDependancyObject(DependencyObject child, string name)
        {
            try
            {
                //We need the logical tree to get our parent
                DependencyObject parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
                DependencyObject lastparent = null;

                //Is the parent our specified control?
                if (name != "" && parent.GetType().ToString() == name) return parent;

                //No, process further
                while (parent != null)
                {
                    string s = parent.GetType().ToString();
                    if (s == name && name != "") return parent;
                    parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
                    if (parent != null) lastparent = parent;
                }
                //Return results
                if (name != "") return null;
                else return lastparent;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is code that I have got from someone else and modified for my own means. What I would like to do is to extend this further by checking to see what category (a hidden property) was used to create the form from and apply a different set of validation rules. In simple terms, if form is not in template mode and category='Server' apply these, if any other category and not in template mode apply the default. I thought I could do this with a simple if else on the private void FormControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e section but I kept getting validation errors.
I'm a novice when it comes to this stuff so I'm hoping this won't be too complicated a request.
Thanks

Comment: minimum example plz? nobody wants to read that huge chunk of code

Comment: that better? I've taken out most of the validation rules, not sure what else I can take out

Comment: Can I ask, what do you mean by category='Server'? Do you want to create one custom control for Incident, Change, Service Request and etc.,  and check to see if this control is on which of the mentioned forms?

Comment: No, it was for a change form but apply different validation depending on the change type, I.e. Standard, emergency etc.

I've now got it working based on an article I found elsewhere that calls different functions depending on th classification selected